# Javascript callback not getting invoked

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm trying to run this snippet and it doesn't seem to be executing callback. I'm trying to understand what's going on.

```js
  function exampleSimpleTask(done) {
    console.log("task", "Before "+new Date().getTime());
    setTimeout(() => done, 2000);
  }

 function demo() {
   alert("Demo Executed");
 }

 exampleSimpleTask(demo); // it doesn't do anything.
 //  exampleSimpleTask.call(null, demo);
 // exampleSimpleTask.call(null, demo.bind(this));
```

I'm not sure why the callback is executed, I'm suspecting its something to do with arrow functions. What happens if  `=>` is replaced by `function()`?

Comment: inside your function exampleSimpleTask you never call the function `done`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside your function `exampleSimpleTask` you never call the function `done`

```
function exampleSimpleTask(done) {
  console.log("task", "Before "+new Date().getTime());
  setTimeout(() => done(), 2000);
}
```

```js
function exampleSimpleTask(done) {
    console.log("task", "Before "+new Date().getTime());
    setTimeout(() => done(), 2000);
  }

 function demo() {
   alert("Demo Executed");
 }

 exampleSimpleTask(demo);
```

Comment: Then how does this work? http://jsfiddle.net/w1xLvzef/

I've extracted bits and pieces from this task runner problem.

Comment: @TechnoCorner When you pass parameters a function is immediately invoked. All of those that are working are working because of that.

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to call the `done()` function inside the lambda expression. The code below should work:

```js
  function exampleSimpleTask(done) {
    console.log("task", "Before "+new Date().getTime());
    setTimeout(() => done(), 2000);
  }

 function demo() {
   alert("Demo Executed");
 }

 exampleSimpleTask(demo); // it doesn't do anything.
 //  exampleSimpleTask.call(null, demo);
 // exampleSimpleTask.call(null, demo.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the parenthesis for call the **demo** method:

```js
function exampleSimpleTask(done)
{
    console.log("task", "Before "+new Date().getTime());
    setTimeout(() => done(), 2000);
}

function demo()
{
    alert("Demo Executed");
}

exampleSimpleTask(demo); // it doesn't do anything.
```

As an alternative, you can simple put the name of the method on the **setTimeout()** function, like this:

```js
function exampleSimpleTask(done)
{
    console.log("task", "Before " + new Date().getTime());
    setTimeout(done, 2000);
}

function demo()
{
    alert("Demo Executed");
}

exampleSimpleTask(demo); // it doesn't do anything.
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for the arrow function in `setTimeout`. The first argument to `setTimeout()` is the function you want to execute when the time is reached, and `done` contains a reference to the function, so just pass it directly.

```js
  function exampleSimpleTask(done) {
    console.log("task", "Before "+new Date().getTime());
    setTimeout(done, 2000);
  }

 function demo() {
   alert("Demo Executed");
 }

 exampleSimpleTask(demo); // it doesn't do anything.
 //  exampleSimpleTask.call(null, demo);
 // exampleSimpleTask.call(null, demo.bind(this));
```

Comment: You could probably shed more light on my actual problem then. I'm curious on how does this work? jsfiddle.net/w1xLvzef I've extracted bits and pieces from this task runner problem that I was trying to solve inititally.

Comment: I explained how it works. `done` contains a reference to the function. `setTimeout` calls that function when the timeout is reached.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks for the time.